# How to wait for the network request to be fulfilled asynchronously, but process the result in the main thread?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, async-await, .net-4.6

I am working with Unity3d, with .NET 4.6 support, and need to work with network requests. I want to do it in the async matter, but as unity is not thread safe, you cannot access any of it's api from any thread other than the main one.

I am sure that the `WebClient`'s async method's callbacks fire in the background thread, so i discarded that variant some time ago.

But with the recent addition of .NET 4.6 to my project i was able to use the TAP and async/await in such a manner, that after the async waiting - with `await`, my code executes in the main, unity thread. I want to achieve something like that with handling web requests, too. Is there some Task-based Api for networking there, or something that executes in the main thread, just delayed?

Comment: Avoid using `await` in Unity. Just use WebClient in another Thread then do callback in the main thread when the request is done....By the way, there you can use Unity's `WWW` or `UnityWebRequst` class for web requests without any Thread.

Comment: @Programmer i was setting the callback for `DownloadStringAsync` for `WebClient`, and recieved an error that unity give you when you access it's API from another thread, so i presume all those callbacks are called from the background thread used for waiting. As for await - i find the TAP much, much more elegant than callbacks and coroutines for async code, and i am aware of the coroutine based WWW class(and new UnityWebRequest)

Comment: Ok. Post your code, the error line and I will show you a solution.

Comment: @Programmer .NET 4.6 was added in Unity partly to be able to use TAP, not sure why you'd recommend against that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know of the new support and have left an answer about that here before. I just think that using `async` and `await` won't solve the current OP's problem. It should be avoided in Unity or game apps because async method will allocate a new Task object each time it is used. This issue is still in C# 6. Until it is fixed, it can slow down a game if used heavily.  Coroutine should  instead.

Comment: @Programmer I plan to use the TAP not in the game exactly, but more when dealing with auth - Firebase, Facebook, Twitter SDKs, so i presume that allocating an object(or a few, when chained(not more than 3 for at the moment)) while in the menu, or motly on startup is the reasonable price for that gorgeous syntax they give us?

Comment: Fine if you are using it once. if it is something that is called more often then use another method. If TAP works fine for you now then go with it. If not, see my first and second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the `.NET 4.6` added new methods for the WebClientClass, now the async one's have [an overload returning a Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159424(v=vs.110).aspx)

I am using it like this:

```
        string profilePicUrl = await  _apiCaller.GetProfilePictureUrlAsync();

        using(var web = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] picBytes = await web.DownloadDataTaskAsync(profilePicUrl);

            // unity api here works because we are back in the main thread
            // as async returns you to the contex in which you started
            var profilePicTexture = new Texture2D(4, 4);
            profilePicTexture.LoadImage(picBytes);
            return profilePicTexture;
        }
```